# Vba code for vlookup when sheet names are going to be different

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating my first macro, to be honest I have learned only by doing researches and its been a bit but I am having problems to insert a Vlookup in a range since the Sheet1 will always have different name depending on the week #

I have tried this

```
Range("I2:I" & lr3).Function = "VLookup(A2," & Sheet1.Range("A1:I" & lr1) & ", 9, 0)"
```

lr(and number) has been used to identify the number of rows used in sheet 1, 2 or 3, any suggestions?

Comment: Try `Range("I2:I" & lr3).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2," & Sheet1.Range("A1:I" & lr1).Address & ", 9, 0)"`

Comment: Thank you very much, just added the sheet name after A2, just like this

Range("I2:I" & lr3).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!" & Sheet1.Range("A1:I" & lr1).Address & ", 9, 0)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `Application.Worksheetfunction`:

```
Sub Lookup()
  Dim ws as worksheet: set ws =   Thisworkbook.Worksheets(“Sheet1”)
        
  Ws.Range(“I2:I” & lr3).Value = Application.Worksheetfunction.Vlookup(“A2”, ws.Range(“A1:I” & lr1).Address, 9, 0)

End Sub
```